# HowTo make restoreState() and saveState() work correctlly to QTableView class?

Tags: qt, save, restore, qtableview

First of all, I wanted to say, that my problem was already discuss here, on SO, and [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163030/qt-qtableview-and-horizontalheader-restorestate). But the answers are not the good ones...

So, here is the **problem**: I have a `QTableView` class, with a simple `model`, connected with `tableView->setModel(model);` method. For example, I have 4-5 columns. I started up my project application and made some changes with columns width. After I pressed Exit, my project app save state of the `tableView->horizontalHeader()->saveState();` data with `QSettings` to file. And when I starts up my app again, it makes something like this:

```
tableView->horizontalHeader()->restoreState(/* data from settings ini file */);
```

But, nothing happens! The columns widths has standard width. They are not changed with my stored values! :(

Thanks!

---

PS: This problem not become apparent with `QTreeView` class. With `QTreeView` all is ok!

Comment: restoreState() returns true or false to indicate if it was successful. Does yours return true?

Comment: @Arnold Spence With all my `QTableView`'s and `QTreeView`'s I got *true* value when doing restoreState()...

Comment: When, in your startup, are you calling restoreState()? Some brief searching seems to suggest that you want to wait until the app is finished starting up and initializing everything. As an experiment, you may try adding a button or menu to your app to invoke the restore after it is running and see if it works out.

Comment: @Arnold Hm, still I'm thinking that it's only `QTableView` base class problem - Qt bug. Because, I tried to restore state with simple Qt Demo Examples (with QTableViews), and still no luck. I don't want to add extra code to my project, because, I think basic Qt features (save/restore headers state) have to work right! But I will try one more example, save/restore header settings from the memory while program run ..

Comment: Memory saveState/restoreState methods worked!..

Comment: That's good. So there is something wrong with your code for persisting to a file with QSettings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but everything is working fine for me. Here is what I did :

With Qt-Designer, I put a `QTableView` (named `tbvTest`) on my form.

In the constructor of my form, here is what I've written :

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->tbvTest->setModel(new TableModel);

    QSettings MySetting(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "Test");
    QByteArray MyArray = MySetting.value("column_width", "").toByteArray();
    ui->tbvTest->horizontalHeader()->restoreState(MyArray);
}
```

(note that in my `main.cpp`, I set the [ApplicationName](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qcoreapplication.html#applicationName-prop), [OrganizationName](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qcoreapplication.html#organizationName-prop) and [OrganizationDomain](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qcoreapplication.html#organizationDomain-prop))

In the destructor of my form, here is what I've written :

```
Widget::~Widget()
{
    QByteArray MyArray = ui->tbvTest->horizontalHeader()->saveState();
    QSettings MySetting(QSettings::IniFormat, QSettings::UserScope, "Test");
    MySetting.setValue("column_width", MyArray);

    delete ui;
}
```

If I run the application and change the column width, quit the app and run it again, the column widths are correctly restored.

Is there something I'm doing different from you ?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I'll try your example as soon as possible. I made all the same things, but a little bit complex. After I get the success result, I'll mentions here about it!

Comment: Making question answered, because I had promissed! %)