# Qt QTreeWidget save columns order

Tags: qt, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

How can I save the QTreeWidget column order ?

I know it can be done via QTreeView from this post

[HowTo make restoreState() and saveState() work correctlly to QTableView class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656978/howto-make-restorestate-and-savestate-work-correctlly-to-qtableview-class)

but I don't see how I can do it with QTreeWidget.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4):

A QTreeWidget *is* a QTreeView (it inherits it), so any function you can call on a QTreeView, you can also call on a QTreeWidget.

You can get the (only) header from a QTreeView (and therefore also from a QTreeWidget) using its `QTreeView::header()` member function.  For example:

```
QTreeWidget *treeWidget = new QTreeWidget(this);
QByteArray saved = treeWidget->header()->saveState();
```